# Проверка двух текстовых полей на совпадение

Tags: java, многопоточность, javafx

Имеется два текстовых поля для ввода пароля,хочу через поток параллельно проверять совпадают ли они. Если да то подсвечивать их зеленым или под ними выводить лейбл что "password are the same", и наоборот красным "passwords are mismatched each other".Примерно понимаю как это сделать через  Platform.runLater но что то не выходит.

```
void confirmPass() {
    if(PasswordUpField.equals(RepeatPass)) {
        createMessageDialog("Confirming Password", "Confirm Password have done successfylly!", "Okay");
    } else {
        createMessageDialog("Confirming Password", "Ouups, an error occured(", "Okay");
    }
}


void comparison () {
    PasswordUpField.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        Platform.runLater(this::confirmPass);
    });
    RepeatPass.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        Platform.runLater(this::confirmPass);
    });
}
```

Comment: В качестве альтернативы вашей реализации, можно сделать BooleanProperty, который будет true когда текстовые проверти обоих полей совпадают и уже не него поставить ChangeListener

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете для сравнения паролей метод .equals(). Он сравнивает не текст в полях, а их значения в памяти, которые, естественно, будут отличатся друг от друга. Необходимо применять именно этот метод, но только не с самими JPasswordField, а с их текстовой информацией.

```
if(PasswordUpField.getPassword().equals(RepeatPass.getPassword())) {
        createMessageDialog("Confirming Password", "Confirm Password have done successfylly!", "Okay");
} else {
    createMessageDialog("Confirming Password", "Ouups, an error occured(", "Okay");
}
```

Или же можно привести массивы символов к строкам, и уже с ними выполнить сравнение

```
String upPassword = new String(PasswordUpField.getPassword());
String downPassword = new String(RepeatPass.getPassword());
if(upPassword.equals(downPassword)) {
        createMessageDialog("Confirming Password", "Confirm Password have done successfylly!", "Okay");
} else {
    createMessageDialog("Confirming Password", "Ouups, an error occured(", "Okay");
}
```

Буду рад,если смог Вам помочь.